# Crontab crash when running a script that insert a lot of lines in MySQL

Tags: ubuntu, crontab

My crontab is crashing when I run a script that insert alot of lines on MySQL Database, but when I run a script that inser few lines it run properly, is there some configuration file of cron? Maybe some config about use of memory.

Comment: Does this only happen when you run it in crontab, or in a shell too?  How far does it get before the crash.   Any additional information you can provide will help diagnosis.

Comment: if you dont need transaction you could try adding them with INSERT DELAYED.